# Rubymine Editor problem with caret and selecting

Tags: editor, rubymine

I have been trying to solve this problem for 30 hours and i need a help. The problems are

1. when i try to select text caret change mode to overwrite
2. i cant select text by shift+(right,left,up,down)
   when i try do this caret just "jumps" by word to word
3. I can't even use ctrl+с for copy, because the select string dumps selection

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because i install IdeaVim plugin
when i delete it, all began work perfectly

Comment: Hi! Did you install IdeaVim by mistake? How did you do that?

Comment: oh, I am beginner in rails especially in program like RubyMine. This plugin was in "recommended" or something like this, so, I click on install button without mind:)

Comment: That's fine and you are not the only one who faced this problem. We are trying to solve this problem of "accidental installation", but we do not know yet how to do it better. On the featured plugins page, IdeaVim has a yellow warning, but it seems like it should be something more noticeable there. Anyway, thank you for the response!